# Programmatically editing every aspect of navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, navigationbar

I've looked up many different questions on using the navigation bar in iOS7 but none of them show exactly what I want with xib files. I'm trying to create an affect similar to the example below:

[image]

So my question is, can I change the navigation bars height, title font size and have iOS7's blur effect?

I'm using xib files and a framework that allows me to create a sidebar so I can't use a navigation controller. I'm just using the separate navigation bar (in a view) but Xcode won't let me change the height of the navigation bar. The only way Xcode will have the navigation bar stretch behind the status bar is if it is in a navigation controller, which will not work for the sidebar. Also I cannot change the size or font of the title in the navigation bar. I really would like to find out if there is a way I can skip adding the navigation bar in interface builder altogether and add everything programmatically and I f so, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you done any research what so ever into your question? All I did was google your title and found loads of questions, did you even look at the related questions that appeared when typing the title? Because even clicking on some of them provide answers to your question. How about looking at the Apple Documentation for `UINavigationBar` did you do that? And this has nothing to do with the `xcode IDE`

Comment: The UINavigation bar is actually different than the standalone navigation bar. The UINavigation bar is part of the UINavigationController. I cannot use the UINavigationController I just need to use a simple view with a navigation bar on top

Comment: So create a simple `UINavigationBar` at the top what is stopping you?

Answer (score -1):

The height of the navigation bar can't change unless to compensate for the status bar

For the blur effect:

```
navBar.translucent = YES;
```

For the title text properties use the `titleTextAttributes` property, which takes an NSDictionary with the keys from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893

Comment: `"The height of the navigation bar can't change"` well that's not true. Where did you read/hear this? It is very simple to change the height of a `UINavigationBar` Please provide anything back this up with.

Comment: Thanks! Can I make anything else translucent? Maybe an image view to put there instead?

Comment: Yeah u add a centered image view instead of the title text.  Or add a background image to the nav bar

Comment: @Popeye its not that u cant actually change it.  Its that its strongly discouraged todo so.  Apple is very anal about the UI elements, I would agree that its kinda stupid, but it makes sense from wat they are tryin to accomplish

Comment: Everyone knows Apple are Anal about things but since when were they about this? If you are making a `UINavigationBar` programmatically you would need to change the height it would be required of you. Apple have never said anything about discouraging developers not to change the height programmatically this just isn't true. I would strongly recommend you back this statement up with evidence because at the moment it is completely wrong.

Comment: Right so the little bit of research you should have done - In relation to `UINavigationBar`s when being used with `UINavigationController`s the following statement means you can't modify a `UINavigationBar`s frame, bounds or alpha when being used with a `UINavigationController` `"but you must never change its frame, bounds, or alpha values or modify its view hierarchy directly"` This is only when a `UINavigationBar` is being used in the `UINavigationController` not standalone when standalone it is perfectly acceptable to modify these. (Statement came from apple docs)